# How to create a Fake resource for a query using k8s NewBuilder in Unit Test?

Tags: go, kubernetes

In my code, I have a query function using the `Factory.NewBuilder().Do()` in `k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/factory.go` to query my CR in K8S.

Now I want to take some UTs to test my query function, so I use the `TestFactory` in `k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/testing/fake.go` that I can make some fake resource to be queried, however:

1. the fake resource I create by `FakeDynamicClient` can't be found by `NewBuilder().Do()`
2. then I use the `UnstructuredClient` to fake Response, but also tips "error: the server doesn't have a resource type "myCRDresource""

```golang
import (
   cmdtesting "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/testing"
   ...
)

//create my fake CR lists
getFakeClusterVersionList := func(clusterVersions ...*appsv1alpha1.ClusterVersion) *appsv1alpha1.ClusterVersionList {
        res := &appsv1alpha1.ClusterVersionList{
            ListMeta: metav1.ListMeta{
                ResourceVersion: "1",
            },
            Items: make([]appsv1alpha1.ClusterVersion, 0),
        }
        for _, cv := range clusterVersions {
            res.Items = append(res.Items, *cv.DeepCopy())
        }
        return res
}

cvlists := getFakeClusterVersionList(cv1, cv2)

tf = cmdtesting.NewTestFactory()
tf.UnstructuredClient = &fake.RESTClient{
    NegotiatedSerializer: resource.UnstructuredPlusDefaultContentConfig().NegotiatedSerializer,
    Resp:                 &http.Response{StatusCode: http.StatusOK, Header: cmdtesting.DefaultHeader(), Body: cmdtesting.ObjBody(codec, cvlists)},
}

// do my query but fail 
...
```

The TestFactory I used

```golang
type TestFactory struct {
    cmdutil.Factory

    kubeConfigFlags *genericclioptions.TestConfigFlags

    Client             RESTClient
    ScaleGetter        scaleclient.ScalesGetter
    UnstructuredClient RESTClient
    ClientConfigVal    *restclient.Config
    FakeDynamicClient  *fakedynamic.FakeDynamicClient

    tempConfigFile *os.File

    UnstructuredClientForMappingFunc resource.FakeClientFunc
    OpenAPISchemaFunc                func() (openapi.Resources, error)
    FakeOpenAPIGetter                discovery.OpenAPISchemaInterface
}
```

I want to makes some UT for my CRS query and don't need to start a real K8S cluster.